# Remix IDE dont compile the contract I selected

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

[contract in select box[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i3KZ.png)

I want to compile my contract in remix and it has some files in the selectbox.
I want to compile the contract CoinToken.sol not the Address. When I Select the CoinToken.sol  it will jump to  the address one automatically.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in editor, Remix compiles the file that is currently active in the editor

Comment: yes I did but it just compile partially of the contract. I want to compile the CoinToken.sol and I chose it in the select box but it will jump my choice and compile the address(CoinToken).sol again.

Comment: that was confusing?

Comment: Remix compiles the source code within your source file. So when you have multiple contracts within a single file, it compiles all of them. If you go to the deploy section, then you can deploy each contract.

But need more infos from you actually.